# Best practice for SEO urls(ASCII vs urlencoded UTF8)?

Tags: url, seo, title

I'am building a website where I need to make an url form article title. First option is to convert all utf8 to ASCII. This can be done, because every language has some kind of [Romanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization) available. But I don't know if, for example, for Chinese people romanticized versions of title makes any sense.
Second options is to urlencode utf8 title like Wikipedia does: [[http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/سيارة](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9)](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9).

What are pluses or minuses for both options? 
which version is better to use?

Comment: I too have often wondered and researched best practices when building sites targeting international markets. So far I have not found a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google, for one, has no problems indexing and listing sites with Unicode characters outside of 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: And you shouldn't be concerned with anyone else.

Comment: I think that was sarcasm—but your post didn't imply that Google should be the only search engine considered, so I don't get it either.